# Better way to populate a column with the same number of rows as other columns

Tags: python, dictionary

I am dealing with python dicts of the format:

```py
y = {
    'column_a':[0,1,2],
    'column_b':[3,4,5],
    'column_c':[5,6,7]
}
```

Where each element of the dict represents a column of a table. Each column must have the same number of elements (ie the number of rows in the table, which isn't explicitly provided).

The issue I'm facing is that in order to add another column and populate it with a single value, I have to write a rather nasty line like:

```py
y['column_d'] = [some_value for i in range(len(y[y.keys()[0]]))]
```

**Is there some better/more elegant way of doing this without iterating through the list itself?**

More specifically, **is there a better way of writing**:

```py
len(y[y.keys()[0]])
```

Comment: I highly recommend you to use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of standart one. As I understood, order of elements matters for you.

Comment: It's my fault, I've misunderstood you. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah... I've encountered those "nasty" lines as well.. Here's a suggestion.

```
L = len(y[y.keys()[0]])
y['column_d'] = [some_value] * L
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "iterate" over dict values manually only once:

```
some_value = 1
y['column_d'] = [some_value] * len(next(iter(y.values()))) # python 3
y['column_d'] = [some_value] * len(next(y.itervalues()))   # python 2
```

Or cast `dict_values` to `list` (for *python3*) and get first element:

```
y['column_d'] = [some_value] * len(list(y.values())[0])    # python 3
y['column_d'] = [some_value] * len(y.values()[0])          # python 2
```

**Upd.**

Some comments about @niCkcAMel answer. @ChristianReall-Fluharty noticed in comments that one of reasons why he has chosen this answer is execution speed. I've decided to test it using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

There are 3 methods offered in both answers. Difference between them is in method of length calculation. So, I've done small test module:

```
y = {
    'column_a': [0, 1, 2],
    'column_b': [3, 4, 5],
    'column_c': [5, 6, 7]
}
some_value = 1


def func(L):
    y['column_d'] = [some_value] * L


def function1():
    L = len(y[y.keys()[0]])            # -- Python 2
    # L = len(y[list(y.keys())[0]])    # -- Python 3
    func(L)


def function2():
    L = len(next(y.itervalues()))      # -- Python 2
    # L = len(next(iter(y.values())))  # -- Python 3
    func(L)


def function3():
    L = len(y.values()[0])             # -- Python 2
    # L = len(list(y.values())[0])     # -- Python 3
    func(L)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("function1()", setup="from __main__ import function1"))
    print(timeit.timeit("function2()", setup="from __main__ import function2"))
    print(timeit.timeit("function3()", setup="from __main__ import function3"))
```

So, let's launch tests.

1. [**Python 2.7.16**](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2716/)

   ```
   2.26870775476       # niCk cAMel      (3rd)
   2.14519973907       # Olvin Roght 1st (winner)
   2.1813173881        # Olvin Roght 2nd (2nd)
   ```
2. [**Python 3.7.3**](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-373/)

   ```
   2.396988793         # niCk cAMel      (3rd)
   2.175222899         # Olvin Roght 1st (winner)
   2.3292458960000006  # Olvin Roght 2nd (2nd)
   ```

**Conclusion:** Fastest variant for both python versions is to get iterator object using [`itervalues()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues)/[`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and get next (first) item from iterator using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).

Comment: @ChristianReall-Fluharty, but it'll not iterate over values. Code get iterator and get first value. Size of values doesn't affect on speed at all.

Comment: @ChristianReall-Fluharty, I've added benchmarks, check updated answer, please.

Comment: @ChristianReall-Fluharty, are you ready to slow down your code just to avoid more parentheses?

Comment: @ChristianReall-Fluharty, I think that because answer you've chosen contains slowest variant.

Answer (score 0):

You could process the whole dictionary with a comprehension and not bother getting the size of the elements (assuming it is not out of sync with your previous number of rows):

```
rowsToAdd    = 1
defaultValue = [0] * rowsToAdd  
y = { k:v + defaultValue for k,v in y.items() }
```

*This is assuming all the columns contain the same datatype and want the same default value.*

If each column has a different default value, you could make a separate dictionary with the defaults for each column name and use that in the comprehension:

```
 defaults = {
     'column_a':[0],
     'column_b':['abc'],
     'column_c':[2.5]
     }
 rowsToAdd = 1
 y = { k:v + defaults[k]*rowsToAdd for k,v in y.items() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution, get the length of the first key's values, with `dict.values`, then multiply it as you've done:

```
y['column_d'] = [some_value] * len(list(y.values)[0])
```

And now:

```
print(y)
```

Is going to have `column_d` with your value repeated the right amount of times.